# Pivot table with null column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Using sql server I want to create a pivot table that contains a null column. I tried:

```
SELECT account_no, SUM([500]) AS [500], SUM([NULL]) AS [the_null_col]
FROM (SELECT * FROM source_table) AS x
PIVOT (SUM(amount) FOR amount_debit IN ([500], [NULL])) AS y
GROUP BY account_no
```

but I only get: The incorrect value "NULL" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

I want to use the pivot operator and no other way of creating a pivot table. I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/d7baffc4-f7e1-4cbf-93d9-e1053475b29f/) but the first answer isn't very detailed unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The suggestion in the first answer in your link is to substitute a non null sentinel value in place of `NULL` and use that in the `PIVOT`.

```
SELECT account_no,
       [500],
       [-1] AS [Null]
FROM   (SELECT amount,
               ISNULL(amount_debit, -1) AS amount_debit,
               account_no
        FROM   source_table) AS x 
        PIVOT (SUM(amount) FOR amount_debit IN ([500], [-1])) AS y
```

This seems a bit of a hack and is vulnerable to breaking if you don't choose a value that *can* never appear in the data.

I'd do this without using the `PIVOT` keyword then it is trivial to check `IS NULL`.

```
SELECT account_no,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN amount_debit = 500 THEN amount
           END) AS [500],
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN amount_debit IS NULL THEN amount
           END) AS [NULL]
FROM   source_table
GROUP  BY account_no
```

Comment: So it simply isn't possible with the pivot operator?

Comment: @user764754 - `IN` has same semantics as `=` and does not evaluate to true for `NULL` (except possibly if you change the `ANSI_NULLS` setting. I haven't bothered testing this as it is deprecated)